# I am able to ping ansible nodes/target machine on aws ec2 as root but not as a user

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

I am able to ping ansible nodes/target machine on aws ec2 as root but not as a user. ansible ping throws below error:

```
node1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

***node1*** is target/slave machine. See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCEp1.png) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to configure key for ssh. Quick ones are having private key under student user’s default ssh directory `~/.ssh` or specifying the location of private key file like `ansible all -m ping --private-key <PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH>`.

Have a look at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/766254/ansible-ping-fails-host-unreachable) for quick reference. You may go through [this doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html) as well.

Comment: thanku for the reply but how can i do this please explain ??

Comment: Did you check the accepted answer in the post link I have given?

Comment: Sorry, not able to chat now. Which part is unclear? Can you explain?

Comment: i have to change in config file anything??

Comment: if you have the private key file then execute the command like... `ansible all -m ping --private-key <PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH>`. Set the PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH with the location you have.

Comment: sorry but which key are u talking about , ssh key or aws key and not able to understand the path to be given .... help

Comment: The error clearly says ssh key which in this case will be required to connect to the target server. I believe you have the private key under root user that you can get and use while connecting using student user. If you are unfamiliar with SSH key or key generation then I would recommend checking these out https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key and https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/

Comment: i have done ls on /user/.ssh and there are id_rsa  ,id_rsa.pub , known_hosts
 these 3 files ,so key is generated i think...

Comment: By `/user/.ssh` do you mean .ssh directory under student user's home directory which generally is `/home/student/.ssh`? If yes then check content of your id_rsa.pub is available at your target hosts `/home/student/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: so u are saying i have to copy content of home/student/.ssh/id_rsa (my controller) to the target machine , i am running a command "ssh-copy-id root@172-31-7-250" (my target/host/node machine ip but this gives me error .. please give ur mail id so i can mail  the screenshots

Comment: Use `ssh-copy-id -i /home/student/.ssh/id_rsa root@172.31.7.250`. One thing to note, if you are logged in as `student` in control machine and use `ansible ping` without username then it will try to connect as `student` in target machine. If you want to use `root` user for pinging then use `ansible all -m ping -u root`

Comment: ansible all -m ping -u root this is working but can't i ping without using '-u root'  also suppose i create a user "devops" in node/target machine then i run ansible all -m ping -u devops its not working , how can i do that .

Comment: You have all the information around this issue now to work on it on your own. Please check the references and explanations in this thread.